# Hi, currently getting a formatting type error and am stumped, any fresh eyes want to lend me a new perspective?

Tags: python, typeerror

So i'm currently on a course, and one of the objectives for today is to recreate the fizzbuzz game, using a for loop and ranges. I think I pretty much have the objective down but am getting a type error and am too stubborn to look up a solution.

This is my current code:

```py
total = 0
for number in range(1, 101):
    if total % 3 == 0:
        total = 'Fizz'
    elif total % 5 == 0:
        total = 'Buzz'
    elif total % 3 and 5 == 0:
        total = 'Fizz Buzz'

    print(number)
```

This is the error I am receiving:

```
line 3, in <module>
    if total % 3 == 0:
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Anyone able to point me in the right direction as to what I am doing wrong? I'm stumped and have tried adding str() to certain parts to see if that fixes the issue.

Currently using python 3.9.1 and am using vs-code to code in.

Edit: thanks for all the helpful prods and suggestions, figured it out :)

Comment: Please provide the **full** error message.

Comment: You do `total = 'Fizz'` & then in the next loop `total % 3` - `total` is a string now. `%` for strings is formatting. Use the correct variable.

Comment: Unrelated to the problem at hand, but waiting to bite you right after: what do you expect `total % 3 and 5 == 0` to do exactly? :)

Comment: Even though you're supposedly doing FizzBuzz, the only thing that you're doing with `number` is printing it.

Comment: I was kind of expecting it to check numbers that were divisible by 3 and 5 xD @spectras I am still really new so I wasn't sure if that was right.

Comment: @Spookr This is evaulated as `(total % 3) and (5 == 0)`.

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean @rdas , so in the actual loop i change total or what? I'm kind of confused if i'm being honest.

Comment: Ahh thank you @Countour-Integral makes more sense having brackets there.

Comment: @Spookr the brackets make it more clear how python will interpret it. And that is not what you wanted it to: `5 == 0` is always `False`, so the condition is always `False`. The keywords `and` and `or` are logical operations, in the sense "proposition A is true and proposition B is true". They are not aggregations.

Comment: …thus you cannot express "x is divisible by 3 and 5", you have to write "x is divisible by 3 and x is divisible by 5". Thus, `(x % 3 == 0) and (x % 5 == 0)`.

Comment: @spectras ahh that makes sense, so if using an and statement where both affect the same item, I should have them in parenthesis instead of just as one long line

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on the comment from @rdas:

In the first execution of the loop:
`total = 0`
so in the first if statement the condition is true `(0%3 ==0)`
which sets `total` to 'Fizz' on line 4.

In the second execution of the loop:
`total = 'Fizz'`.
So as suggested, `total` is a string at this point and for strings the `%` is used for [string formatting](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/).
Since 3 is not a valid set of arguments for `total` as a format string you get the error that you're seeing.

That being said, this probably means that there's a problem with how total is being used in your code!

Comment: I think i understand, i'm still trying to figure this out, so maybe total should be placed somewhere else? Or not used at all?

Comment: I would suggest asking yourself, what is the value in `total` supposed to represent in my code? Keeping this to one purpose simplifies things greatly when I am coding :)

Comment: Or like you said, if the variable serves no purpose in the flow of the code, then it should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Its because you are setting total to a string, then using a `%` operator on that.

For integers, `%` means mod, for strings it is part of the formatting for printing them.

If you print out the value of number in your loop you can see it gets round the loop the first time, then breaks when total has been changed to a string.